# I am using glassfish-3.1 sever and primefaces. When I run project it gives this error

Tags: java, primefaces

WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /web, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called...

`

Answer (score 3):

In your glassfish-web.xml(create it if it doesn't exist), add `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` within `<glassfish-web-app error-url="">` like this:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
 <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: I try to add this code into my web.xml but when I put this code it gives error and can not be deployed

Comment: you have to add it to your glassfish-web.xml (glassfish-specific deployment descriptor), if you don't have it, create it.